# Error evaluting CoreML custom layer "----" on GPU?

Tags: metal, coreml, metalkit

I get this error without any other details.

This is the metal code

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void copy(texture2d_array<half, access::read>  in_texture [[texture(0)]] ,
                 texture2d_array<half, access::write> out_texture [[texture(1)]],
                 ushort3 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    if (gid.x >= out_texture.get_width() || gid.y >= out_texture.get_height()) {
        return;
    }

    const float4 x = float4(in_texture.read(gid.xy, gid.z));
    out_texture.write(half4(x), gid.xy, gid.z);
}
```

This is the computer buffer implementation.

```
-(BOOL)encodeToCommandBuffer:(id<MTLCommandBuffer>)commandBuffer inputs:(NSArray<id<MTLTexture>> *)inputs outputs:(NSArray<id<MTLTexture>> *)outputs error:(NSError *__autoreleasing  _Nullable *)error
{
    auto encoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
    [encoder setTexture: input  atIndex: 0];
    [encoder setTexture: output atIndex: 1];
    [encoder setComputePipelineState:_pipeline];

    // Set the compute kernel's threadgroup size of 16x16
    MTLSize thread_group_size = MTLSizeMake(16, 16, 1);

    MTLSize thread_group_count = MTLSizeMake(0, 0, 1);

    // Calculate the number of rows and columns of threadgroups given the width of the input image
    // Ensure that you cover the entire image (or more) so you process every pixel
    thread_group_count.width   = (input.width  + thread_group_size.width -  1) / thread_group_size.width;
    thread_group_count.height  = (input.height + thread_group_size.height - 1)  / thread_group_size.height;

    [encoder dispatchThreadgroups:thread_group_count threadsPerThreadgroup:thread_group_size];
    [encoder endEncoding];
}
```

Based off of : https://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-custom-layers/

What can I use to pin down the error? 
I tried using an empty `encodeToCommandBuffer` and I still get the same error.

Comment: What I would try is running this code in a separate app, without using Core ML. That will make it a lot easier to debug and figure out what is going wrong. Also: does it work OK on the CPU?

Comment: Yep, it works ok on CPU. I am just doing basic copy op.

Comment: Then figure out if the Metal kernel works OK on its own without Core ML. Also make sure the inputShapes that are passed into the layer are not all zeros when running on the GPU.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Unrelated, but in your blog you mention that CoreML is slower than metal by 2x. Is this still the case?

Comment: It depends on the device and the kind of model you're trying to run. On the iPhone XS, Core ML is often much faster than Metal because it has access to the Neural Engine.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Thanks for the reply. I am going off of this blog : https://machinethink.net/blog/mobilenet-ssdlite-coreml/ . The last paragraph specifically. Is it still true? That Metal is about 2x faster on devices prior to XS?

Thanks a lot! Do you think apple will give metal access to the Neural Engine? They are adding more work for devs with their current strategy.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Anyways I wanted to thank you for your blog! You are acting as a force multiplier, helping devs get more things done. Thank you for your contributions!

Comment: Yes, nothing changed on the older devices (as far as I can tell, but I might be doing something wrong). I doubt Metal will ever use the Neural Engine because it's an API for the GPU while the Neural Engine (ANE) is a completely different chip. But we might get a separate API for the ANE (hopefully).